# WWW and non-WWW HTTPS redirect

Tags: node.js, virtualhost, openlitespeed

I have node.js app running on virtual host via openlitespeed and i have issues with redirecting.

I decide to have example.eu as main.

when i type http://example.com into URL it redirect to https://example.com (correct)

but

when i type http://www.example.com into URL it gave me DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

the seobility redirect checker gave me lot of errors and i just dont know how to fix them.

SEO checker give me errors to HTTP redirects:

"The redirect to https for this site is not configured correctly"
and
"this website uses URLs with ww and nonw-www subdomain. this may cause duplicate content and bad links to your website"

I have just 1 listener on my openlitespeed web panel:

### Listener name: @
IP Address: Any
Port: 443
Secure: Yes

On this listener i set up vhost maping to my vhost.

In Vhost rewrite rules i have this:
 `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] RewriteRule ^ https://superparmeni.eu%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]`

SSL is added on listener and vhost too.

On my domain settings i have CNAME record for WWW and A record for non-www (@)

Where i doing mistake please?

i tried evertithing and im desperate now